# How to parse llvm bitcode block 2

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

Currently, I'm writing an LLVM bitcode parser just for fun, however, I've run into an issue where the parser just throws an error because it reads wrong values from the file. I think I understood the way the file is structured and if I try and parse a simple program the output of my parser looks like this:

```
/*
Attributes are written in brackets, a colon is followed by a value.
The first Block attribute is its kind, the second one is its length, and the third one is its layer. The reason that a layer 1 is printed within the same level as a 
level 0 here, is that every block get's printed as soon as it has been parsed, so the 
BlockInfo at layer one is part of a block that fails to parse.
*/
Block(Identification,160,0):
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 1
│   ├── Array(Char)
│   └── Char
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 1
│   ├── Array(Char)
│   │   ├── Char: L
│   │   ├── Char: L
│   │   ├── Char: V
│   │   ├── Char: M
│   │   ├── Char: 1
│   │   ├── Char: 2
│   │   ├── Char: .
│   │   ├── Char: 0
│   │   ├── Char: .
│   │   └── Char: 1
│   └── Char
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 2
│   └── VBR(6)
└── Abbreviation:
    ├── Literal: 2
    └── VBR(6): 0

Block(BlockInfo,704,1):
├── Record(1):
│   └── 14
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Fixed(3)
│   ├── VBR(8)
│   ├── Array(Fixed)
│   └── Fixed(8)
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 1
│   ├── VBR(8)
│   ├── Array(Fixed)
│   └── Fixed(7)
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 1
│   ├── VBR(8)
│   ├── Array(Char)
│   └── Char
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 2
│   ├── VBR(8)
│   ├── Array(Char)
│   └── Char
├── Record(1):
│   └── 11
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 1
│   └── Fixed(4)
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 4
│   └── VBR(8)
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 11
│   ├── Fixed(4)
│   ├── Fixed(4)
│   └── VBR(8)
├── Abbreviation:
│   └── Literal: 2
├── Record(1):
│   └── 12
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 20
│   ├── VBR(6)
│   ├── Fixed(4)
│   ├── VBR(4)
│   └── Fixed(1)
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 56
│   ├── VBR(6)
│   └── Fixed(4)
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 56
│   ├── VBR(6)
│   ├── Fixed(4)
│   └── Fixed(8)
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 2
│   ├── VBR(6)
│   ├── VBR(6)
│   └── Fixed(4)
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 2
│   ├── VBR(6)
│   ├── VBR(6)
│   ├── Fixed(4)
│   └── Fixed(8)
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 3
│   ├── VBR(6)
│   ├── Fixed(4)
│   └── Fixed(4)
├── Abbreviation:
│   └── Literal: 10
├── Abbreviation:
│   ├── Literal: 10
│   └── VBR(6)
├── Abbreviation:
│   └── Literal: 15
└── Abbreviation:
    ├── Literal: 43
    ├── Fixed(1)
    ├── Fixed(4)
    ├── Array(VBR)
    └── VBR(6)

Block(Unknown(2),198944,2):
```

As you can see, the last block it is trying to parse has the ID 2 and fails to read its correct size. Does Block id 2 has to be parsed in a different way than other Blocks?